# Using OkHttp in library dependency free for the app

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-library, okhttp

A few years back, we have developed an Android SDK that exposes an API.

Back then we used DefaultHttpClient and HttpResponse which have been more than deprecated ! Volley, OkHttp and Retrofit seem to be elegant solutions to handle network need so I have added a dependency to my .aar library using gradle which is :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
}
```

Doing so I was hoping to have okhttp as a dependency to my library but not to the app that was going to use it.

As a matter of fact, it seems that I was wrong since when I try to use the SDK with okhttp, my app crashes and I get that:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.SDKExample, PID: 11977
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient;
...
```

Since this SDK is used by B2B customers, I really can't afford to ask them to install the okhttp in their app (which seems to be a solution to make the whole thing work).

Is there any solution to this ?

Thanks guys !

Comment: "when I try to use the SDK with okhttp, my app crashes" -- how exactly does the app link to the library? If you use `compile project(':library')` or `compile `...`) to reference an artifact in an artifact repository, transitive dependencies should work.

Comment: i do compile name:'sdk-1.2.2', ext:'aar'

Comment: That suggests that you are trying to load a bare AAR file. That will not work. Publish your SDK to an artifact repository (Maven Central, JCenter, one of your own, etc.). The POM file that gets published with the AAR will contain details of your transitive dependencies, so apps that depend on your artifact know to download `okhttp` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, I will try that and let you know ;)

Comment: So basically If I get you right, there is no way for me to do that unless I get my library published ?

Comment: Correct. An AAR does not contain anything about its dependencies, just like a JAR does not contain anything about its dependencies. That metadata is held elsewhere, such as in the POM file of a Maven-style artifact repository. Note that a Maven-style repository is just a directory structure. My CWAC libraries are published on Amazon S3, for example. There are also commercial-grade Maven repository servers, if you prefer. You can even ship a Maven repository in ZIP format for people to unpack -- this is how you get the Android support libraries, for example.

Comment: I assume there will be no problem I my sdk uses ok http version 2 but let's say I implement the version 2 in my sdk, then the version 2 rolls out and the app uses now the version 3. Won't there be problems such as conflicts ?

Comment: Possibly. OkHttp is taking an approach where major versions change the artifact name and Java package, so an app can use both the older major version and a newer major version. In general, though, it is entirely possible for an app developer to be forced to use a different version of some library than they want, because some *other* library uses that version and they need to abide by what that library needs. This is not unique to Java; you can run into this with Ruby gems, Node modules, etc.

Comment: So a good practice would be to avoid using third party libraries which I kind of new. There million dollars question would be then, what would be a good approach to replace the use of DefaultHttpClient and HttpResponse without using libraries since even google recommends using Volley ? thanks for you time by the way :)

Comment: "So a good practice would be to avoid using third party libraries which I kind of new" -- I disagree. "what would be a good approach to replace the use of DefaultHttpClient and HttpResponse without using libraries" -- your only options are `HttpURLConnection` or writing your own HTTP client API using `Socket`.

Comment: You would rather use a third party library and add that dependency rather than use HttpURLConnection ?

Comment: Yes, because `HttpURLConnection` sucks. :-)

Comment: You could declare your dependency as provided
`dependencies {
    provided 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
}`
Then any user of your lib would need to include the lib as a compile dependency and you wouldn't have to bundle the okhttp lib with your aar - it becomes a responsibility of your lib user.